# drawing outside a view's canvas, can it be OK?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a custom view that extends ImageView and displays an image and a text header. The text is drawn via `drawRect` and `drawText` overriding `onDraw`.

[image]

- The first image is the typical use case: The header is inside the canvas bounds.
- I'd like to be able to **draw the header outside the canvas bounds**. If I just draw it outside the bounds, just like image 2, the result is correct, ie. the rectangle is drawn outside the canvas and the text too.

However, I wonder if this **works by accident** and what kind of problems I may expect. I suppose it's a bad thing to draw outside the canvas bounds, but it'd be very convenient for me because I won't need to further complicate this custom view, or wrap it inside a container, or create another view, etc... I've only tested it on a couple devices I own and it works...

Can anybody share some thoughts on why this is OK, it doesn't really matter,  or is very wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I've found a legit way to do this:

- set the **bottom padding** to the header size plus the blank space
- draw normally, now everything's inside the canvas and the imageView is adjusted to the requested padding, leaving the bottom padding area free to draw my header :P